# SSML output with custom language

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I'm building a simple alexa skill.

I'm trying to output a text message (in italian) with some english word in it, but i don't found how let it works..

#### 1 try

```
return github.getFollowersCount(search)
  .then((count) => {
    const speechOutput = `${search} ha ${count} <lang xml:lang="en-GB">follower</lang>`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput);
  })
```

#### 2 try

```
return {
  ssml: `<speak>Hai ${count} <lang xml:lang="en-GB">follower</lang></speak>`,
  type: 'SSML',
};
```

#### 3 try

```
const speechOutput = `${search} ha ${count} <lang xml:lang="en-GB">follower</lang>`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(escaleTag(speechOutput));
```

I don't find any docs or way to make it works.
Also [ssml-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssml-builder) seems doesn't support the `lang` tag..

Do you have any suggestions? What the handler function should return?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should totally work. Have you tried with `<lang xml:lang="en-US">` or with another language?

Answer (score 3):

SSML does support the `lang` tag, but am not sure if it'll take it with the default voice. Here is an SSML snippet that I use that seems to be working fine.

`<voice name="Brian"><lang xml:lang="en-GB">Hello there</lang>.</voice>`

According to the official documentation, the following voices are supported for their respective languages:

English, American (en-US): Ivy, Joanna, Joey, Justin, Kendra, Kimberly, Matthew, Salli

English, Australian (en-AU): Nicole, Russell

English, British (en-GB): Amy, Brian, Emma

English, Indian (en-IN): Aditi, Raveena

German (de-DE): Hans, Marlene, Vicki

Spanish, Castilian (es-es): Conchita, Enrique

Italian (it-IT): Carla, Giorgio

Japanese (ja-JP): Mizuki, Takumi

French (fr-FR): Celine, Lea, Mathieu